# Spring JPA - One to one but keep history

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I some classes classes that were used to create an object like this:

{
name: "Foo Inc",
...
accountingConnection: {
id: 123,
token: "abc",
createdAt: <some_date>,
disconnectedAt: null
}
}

Here is what I have for the JPA files:

Business.java:

```
...
  @JsonManagedReference
  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "business", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private AccountingConnection accountingConnection;
...
```

AccountingConnection.java

```
...
      @JsonBackReference
      @OneToOne()
      @JoinColumn(
          name = "business_id",
          referencedColumnName = "id",
          nullable = false
      )
      private Business business;
...
```

Now I need to change this to keep a history of the connections, I would like to keep all the connections in a table, but when calling the business object, only return the one without a disconnect date, and work with that normally, is that possible without manually looking up each, or looping through a OneToMany array / picking one without having multiple definitions for the business dto?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply have a `List< AccountingConnection>` oldConnection`attribute that you update whenever the`accountingConnection` changes.